# How to get from url "index.php?option=com_event&view=delete&id=17" the id content

Tags: joomla

I am implementing a function to delete a row in database table from front end joomla.

Basically i create a link with url index.php?option=com_event&view=delete&id=17, once click on the link, it will call the function delete() in controller, in which it will call the delete_event() in the model. in the model, the delete_event() will fetch the event id from the url id, and delete the event with this id.

Firstly, I don't know whether the logic is correct or not.

Secondly, how to fetch the event id from the url in the delete_event() model?

i am trying:

```
$app = JFactory::getApplication();
$menu  = $app->getMenu();
```

I don't think it is correct.

Please help me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flow you said is ok with Joomla standard.

In your controller function you can get the input id using below methods.

```
$removal_id = JRequest::getInt('id',0);
```

From this controller you can pass this as argument to the model or retrieve directly on the model.

```
$model  = $this->getModel('Article');//your model name
$model->delete_event($removal_id);
```

Make sure you have included Joomla HTML token in the form and check that inside your controller function to prevent direct url access.

check Joomla token like.

```
JRequest::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));
```

After the removal you need to redirect back to the view just use like.

```
$this->setRedirect('url','message');
```

For more standards you can use Joomla native functions to do the task, for that you have to set your table structure properly then check [this](http://docs.joomla.org/API16%3aJTable/delete)

Hope its make sense..

Comment: Hi, how can i pass the argument to the model from the controller.

Comment: And is the flow like this, the controller calls the model function, how could it be that the controller pass argument to model?

Comment: what is the different between $model= & JModelLegacy::getInstance('Event','EventModel'); and $this->getModel('Event');//which is my model name.

Comment: and in my delete_event() function definition, i didnot set an argument..do i need to do so?

Comment: if you are using $model= & JModelLegacy::getInstance('Event','EventModel');  its also same as using $this-> better to use this bcoz right now you are in that component if the component models name like event.php by default its took so no need of calling with JModelLegacy:, if u r paasing with arument from controller to model then should have argument to retrieve that in definition too.

Comment: thank you! Last question, in the definition of delete_event() is it like delete_event(& $id) or delete_event($id)? Thank you.

Comment: no need of &id just $id we are passing with value not reference.. remember your old school day.. :)

Answer (score 1):

Those variables in an address get passed into the page as GET variables. According to the [Joomla docs](http://docs.joomla.org/J1.5%3aRetrieving_and_Filtering_GET_and_POST_requests_with_JRequest%3a%3agetVar), you can use `JRequest::getVar('id')`. The alternate form with a second parameter allows you to easily handle the case of an unset id.

EDIT: As pointed out by Lodder, the above is for Joomla versions <2.5 (my mistake). Here is the [updated docs link](http://docs.joomla.org/Retrieving_request_data_using_JInput) for 2.5+, which is likely more relevant.

Comment: Am i going to call it in the delete_event() or delete()?

Comment: which means, in the model, or the controller?

Comment: @user2870092 The controller will be the one seeing the request, so that should be responsible for dispatching the deletion.

Comment: @esel +1 Answer with Joomla standards!.

Comment: yes, good to see that Joomla standards have been used ;), however this method would only be recommended if the OP is using Joomla 1.5 or 2.5, not Joomla 3.x

Comment: @Lodder Bah, you're right. I'm not a Joomla person, just did some poking around and went with what I saw first. Fixed. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help to get the id from URL

```
if(isset($_GET['id']))
{
$id = $_GET['id'];
}
```

and then pass $id to the model for further procedure like this

```
delete_event($id);
```

More specifically for Joomla try this

```
$myabsoluteurl=JURI::base(); //for Absolute URL
$mycurrenturl=JURI::current(); //for Current URL
```

and once you get the current URL you can divide it by part using php explode function

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_explode.asp

Comment: its not Joomla standard

Comment: I have written the standards too

Comment: There is no need of absolute url or current url for this case you are using $_GET['id']. that is not recommended in Joomla for receiving post data Joomla's native options like JRequest is using.

Comment: Well if you have complete current URL in hand you can easily get the part you require using explode() function. id in your case. In programming you may have more than one way to achieve the task you can use JRequest Library but I have done the desired task using JURI library many times

Comment: @ITConflux we all know it works, but it's not how Joomla coding should be. The idea behind having a framework is using it to ensure the code is secure, consistent, maintainable and easily understandable by other coders.